# How to get complete list of Method Name's and Doc String in Python Module?

Tags: python

How to get Method Name/Doc String in a Python Module in such a way that I can search if whatever I want is already existing? I should get all method names and doc strings.
I am trying to implement a DRY approach in our Project so if we can have a browsable list of API's, it will be easy for us to search if an existing function existing or atleast some function that does a similar job.

Comment: Create a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file?

Comment: Oh, and what do you have a problem with? Getting the properties from the Python object, or the exporting?

Comment: Why not use [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/examples.html)? Why the hell Excel?

Comment: This is the requirement , so do we have anything existing for this ?
Will read on Sphinx . Getting the API's with Doc String would usually be a common requirement I think . I would like to Publish it to users so that they can check if there is an API already . So Excel or any other suggestions are fine .

Comment: I found [this](http://www.python-excel.org/). That might help.

Comment: Sphinx was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If module/class/method is documented with doc strings you can retrieve such documentation by `__doc__` attribute.

If you want to know what attributes are available for given object (module, class) you can use `dir()` built-in function.

Example for `gnupg` module (not build-in, but open source):

```
>>> import gnupg
>>> dir(gnupg)
['Crypt', 'DeleteResult', 'GPG', 'GenKey', ...
>>> gnupg.Crypt.__doc__
'Handle status messages for --encrypt and --decrypt'
>>>
```

Using `dir()` and `__doc__` you can export those information to CSV file that can be used by Excel.

Comment: Yes Sphinx seems to be a good doc generator though